# How to get Column Number(or index) from Excel Column Letter

Tags: excel, function, character

I have searched through this site and googled for a formula. I need to calculate an Excel column number FROM the letter such as:

```
A=1
B=2
..
AA=27
AZ=52
...
AAA=703
```

The code seems to be 1 digit off after random cycles of the alphabet(AZ -> BA == off digit). It also will seemingly randomly produce the same integer from two different inputs:

```
GetColumnNumber(xlLetter : Text) : Integer //Start of function

 StringLength := STRLEN(xlLetter);
 FOR i := 1 TO StringLength DO BEGIN
 Letter := xlLetter[i];
   IF i>1 THEN
     Count += ((xlLetter[i-1]-64) * (i-1) * 26) - 1;
   Count += (Letter - 64);
 END;
 EXIT(Count); //return value
```

My code example is written in C/AL which is used for Dynamics NAV, but I can write C# or vb.net as well so I wouldn't mind if an example was in either of those languages.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake on my part, I was just doing the math in my head when i was typing. The results i am getting when i run this function against a full series of letters - I get to AZ the next letter is a digit away so if AZ = 52 then BA = 54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA:

```
Public Function GetCol(c As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long, t As Long
    c = UCase(c)
    For i = Len(c) To 1 Step -1
        t = t + ((Asc(Mid(c, i, 1)) - 64) * (26 ^ (Len(c) - i)))
    Next i
    GetCol = t
End Function
```

Comment: I rewrote it for my language(C/AL), but this concept works perfectly

Comment: GetColumnNumbers(c : Text) : Integer

FOR i:= STRLEN(c) DownTo 1 DO BEGIN
    t := t + (c[i]-64) * (POWER(26, STRLEN(c)-i));
END;

EXIT(t);

Answer (score 3):

In VBA:

```
Function ColLetter(C As Integer) As String
  If C < 27 Then
    ColLetter = Chr(64 + C)
  Else
    ColLetter = ColLetter((C - 1) \ 26) & ColLetter((C - 1) Mod 26 + 1)
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA: (Recursive Function)

```
    Function Get_Col_Number(strColName As String, dRunningNo As Integer) As Double
        Dim dCurrentColNo As Double
        Dim dMultipleValue As Double

        strColName = Ucase(strColName)

        If (dRunningNo <= 0) Then Get_Col_Number = 0:   Exit Function

        dCurrentColNo = ((Asc(Mid(strColName, dRunningNo, 1)) - Asc("A") + 1))
        dMultipleValue = 26 ^ (Len(strColName) - dRunningNo)

        Get_Col_Number = (dCurrentColNo * dMultipleValue) + Get_Col_Number(strColName, (dRunningNo - 1))
    End Function
```

Use this Function as below.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim StrGetNoForThisColumnName As String
    StrGetNoForThisColumnName = "Xfd"

    Msgbox "Final Result : " & Get_Col_Number(StrGetNoForThisColumnName, Len(StrGetNoForThisColumnName))
End Sub
```