# Method Range of Object Worksheet failed when inserting column

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I've been working on a macro for a client. Need to insert columns based on cell values.

I use the same code for each value:

```
ws.range(getcolumn(currentColumn + 1) & ":" & getcolumn(currentcolumn +    3)).EntireColumn.Insert
```

That works fine until I hit column 50, and then I get a runtime Error of 1004 that says "Method Range of Object Worksheet Failed"

Why am I getting this error?

Here is the getColumn() function:

```
Function getColumn(columnNumber As Integer) As String

Dim alphaNumber As Integer
Dim iRemainder As Integer
alphaNumber = Int(columnNumber / 27)
iRemainder = columnNumber - (alphaNumber * 26)

If alphaNumber > 0 Then
    getColumn = Chr(alphaNumber + 64)
End If

If iRemainder > 0 Then
    getColumn = getColumn & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
End If


End Function
```

Comment: Did you reach the overall limit of columns in your worksheet?  This limit depends on your version of Excel.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm at column 50 and I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: Could you post your `getcolumn()` function?

Comment: Exactly. So what could be the other causes? This action is supposed to happen a maximum of ten times, each time inserting three columns After the column the select case is at. So around the 9th time is when I get the error. The columns do push them to the right, but right now I'm at column 50, and the code for each Case doesn't change in the way it's inserting columns, so I don't understand where I'm getting the error from

Comment: @PortlandRunner of course I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in your `getColumn()` function.

When `currentcolumn = 50` the getColumn is returning `"A["` because `iRemainder` is 27 so your looking for `Chr(91)` which is `[`

---

Taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17818811/2521004) try this:

```
Function getColumn(columnNumber As Integer) As String
  If columnNumber < 27 Then
     getColumn = Chr(64 + columnNumber)
  Else
     getColumn = getColumn((columnNumber - 1) \ 26) & getColumn((columnNumber - 1) Mod 26 + 1)
  End If
End Function
```

---

I did a basic test using this sub:

```
Sub insertCol()
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For currentcolumn = 1 To 60
        ws.Range(getColumn(currentcolumn + 1) & ":" & getColumn(currentcolumn + 3)).EntireColumn.Insert
    Next currentcolumn
End Sub
```

Comment: See, my update.  I did a basic test that seemed to work well.  See if it works for your case.

Comment: Works great now! Thanks a million!